# Let's get critical: Apr 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How did a prisoner pay back debt?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8392/how-did-a-prisoner-pay-back-debt)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is the significance of the perfect ειρηκεν in 2 Cor 12:9?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8415/what-is-the-significance-of-the-perfect-in-2-cor-129)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is the meaning of the bread of the presence being changed out on a Sabbath?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8234/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-bread-of-the-presence-being-changed-out-on-a-sabbath)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [To what does the time clause connect in Revelation 13:8?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8244/to-what-does-the-time-clause-connect-in-revelation-138)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why is Elohim translated as God rather than gods in Genesis 1:1?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8331/why-is-elohim-translated-as-god-rather-than-gods)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why is the participle ὢν in John 9:25 translated into English as past tense?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8356/why-is-the-participle-in-john-925-translated-into-english-as-past-tense)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Does the Holy Spirit have a name](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8490/does-the-holy-spirit-have-a-name)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How can the 3 Questions be resolved with the math still correct?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8365/how-can-the-3-questions-be-resolved-with-the-math-still-correct)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [When did Joseph, Jesus's father, die?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8245/when-did-joseph-jesuss-father-die)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Ezekiel 28:14 question Hebrew wording](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8438/ezekiel-2814-question-hebrew-wording)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at this, and thought that to do what the evaluation was suggesting, having thoughtfully read the Q&A, I'm looking at 10-15 minutes per question, so 4-5 in an hour....

That seems like a lot! :) Is there value in just doing one or two? or one every now and then as time is available? I'm not sure in the great scheme of things how valuable the pay-off is from this exercise given the time investment. If there was some guidance on this sort of thing, that would be a help. Thanks!

(Perhaps this isn't the sort of "answer" that the question is attempting to elicit, but ... hey, it's meta. :)

Comment: Yes, meta is meta, so answers in the comments please! (I'd also like a answer to this, maybe not really in a comment though)